# Discord.net - Status details

Tags: discord, discord.net, nlp-question-answering

I have a question with the Discord.net´s `Game(string name, ActivityType type, ActivityProperties flags, string details)` what is the string "details" what does it? I tried to change it something but nothing changed.

Yeah not the most "important" question but i would like to know what does "details" do!

Thanks,
Philipp H.

Comment: https://github.com/discord-net/Discord.Net/issues/1233#issue-396296848

Answer (score 0):

Answered by Anu6is (thanks)

I needed the nightly version of discord.net
(github.com/discord-net/Discord.Net/issues/1233#issue-396296848)